# Unable to open application module -> There is an error in invoking javac. A full JDK (not just JRE) is required

Tags: java, javac, payara

We have the server which has Java 8 and Javac 8.
But while trying to access a module(developed using servlet) in the application it shows exception as **"A full JDK (not just JRE) is required"**.

While using command...

```
[pdpadmin@HKDVLE805 /]$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_144
[pdpadmin@HKDVLE805 /]$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
[pdpadmin@HKDVLE805 /]$ which java
/PDP/current-jdk8/bin/java
[pdpadmin@HKDVLE805 /]$ which javac
/PDP/current-jdk8/bin/javac
```

Stack trace

> [2018-08-17T14:24:20.709+0800] [Payara 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1534487060709] [levelValue: 900] [[
>     Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:378)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:119)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Jsr199JavaCompiler.compile(Jsr199JavaCompiler.java:208)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:384)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
>       at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1606)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:821)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:685)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:641)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:573)
>       at com.flextronics.servlet.admin.LoginManagement.processRequest(LoginManagement.java:169)
>       at com.flextronics.servlet.admin.LoginManagement.handleRequest(LoginManagement.java:276)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet.service(HttpRequestHandlerServlet.java:67)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1606)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   ]]

[2018-08-17T14:24:20.711+0800] [Payara 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1534487060711] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[LoginManagement]: Servlet.service() for servlet LoginManagement threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:119)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Jsr199JavaCompiler.compile(Jsr199JavaCompiler.java:208)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:384)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1606)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:821)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:685)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:641)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:573)
    at com.flextronics.servlet.admin.LoginManagement.processRequest(LoginManagement.java:169)
    at com.flextronics.servlet.admin.LoginManagement.handleRequest(LoginManagement.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet.service(HttpRequestHandlerServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1606)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]

Though Javac and Java is same, it is showing excepion. Can you please help me to understand why i am getting JasperException?

Comment: Downvoting this. You should provide some more information such as the stacktrace you're getting, some application details etc etc in order for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: Your glassfish configuration must be pointing to a JRE installation, rather than a JDK, to run with.  Your command line is set up to use the JDK - but it looks like Glassfish is configured differently.

Comment: @moilejter - We are using payrara server(glassfish 4). how to check and change jdk configuration in payara?

Answer (score 0):

your application uses JSPs and to compile them, Payara needs to be running with a JDK and not only with JRE. Check which path is configured in Payara Server - normally it uses the default Java installation, but it can be configured in configured in `glassfish/config/asenv.conf` or in `bin/asadmin`. If in doubt, check which process is running if you start Payara Server.